# Цена всех товаров не сумируется

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не могу додуматься как мне сделать что бы из массива prices возвращался ответ общей цены всех добавленных товаров, сейчас мне выдает цену каждого добавленного товара... Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
{this.state.products.map((products) => (         
                 value.state.cartItems.map((item) =>( products.id === item ? // products.id это id, а item это клик по определенному товару 
                    products.prices.map((prices) => ( 
                        <div>
                        <div className={s.praceTotal}>{value.state.selectValue.slice(0, -4) === prices.currency.symbol ? prices.currency.symbol + " " + (prices.amount  * this.state.quantity).toFixed(3).slice(0, -1)  : null  } </div>
                        </div>
                   ))
                    : null)) ))}
```

Comment: был бы ещё пример массива было бы ещё лучше)

Comment: Обновил описание) Это передаются данные для одного товара

Comment: @Nord prices.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.amount, 0) сумма всех amount , но валюта же разная, поэтому надо прописать доп логику конвертации

Comment: Спасибо за ответ у меня уже есть логика которая отвечает за конвертацию 
value.state.selectValue.slice(0, -4) )) Я попробовал  вставить ваш код и у меня вылазит белый экран(
Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, на моем коде написать исправление и что бы эта строка осталась , так как тут конструкция тотал цены, мне главное что бы prices.amount изменился и , пожалуйста, напишите это как ответ что бы я мог защищать это как правильный ответ. Спасибо больше

Comment: ошибка в консоли Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: prices.reduce is not a function

Comment: Я протестировал ваш код, если вытягивать reduce из products.prices совместно с остальным кодом который должен быть, то приложение становится не жизнеспособно, если использовать ваш код внутри products.prices.map, то ваш код также не взаимодействует с остальной частью кода. Возможно я что-то не до понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prices.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return acc + item.amount
}, 0)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ, но вызывает ошибку. Мне нужно что бы вызывалось внутри этой части кода и вместо prices.amount, в этом то у меня и проблема что я не могу додуматься как это сделать

products.prices.map((prices) => ( 
                        <div>
                        <div className={s.praceTotal}>{value.state.selectValue.slice(0, -4) === prices.currency.symbol ? prices.currency.symbol + " " + (prices.amount  * this.state.quantity).toFixed(3).slice(0, -1)  : null  } </div>
                        </div>
                   ))

Comment: Дополню ответ:  

products.prices.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return acc + item.amount
}, 0)

Он работает, но используя его невозможно использовать другую часть кода без которой невозможно. Мне нужно исправить только prices.amount что бы он отображал одно число + суммировал все числа, а получается что код ломает всю конструкцию.

Comment: Хоть я не до конца понимаю как правильно ваш ответ применить к моему коду, но ваш ответ правильный,спасибо!